# How to add user specified values from a hash

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a program that would take a string from user input and return the 'value' of the word where `a=1`, `b=2`, `c=3` etc. i.e. `"cab" = 6`.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to break down the user input variable and have it added together:

```
print "Give us a word to calculate: "
word = gets.chomp
alphabet = Hash[
  "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3,
  "d" => 4, "e" => 5, "f" => 6,
  "g" => 7, "h" => 8, "i" => 9,
  "j" => 10, "k" => 11, "l" => 12,
  "m" => 13, "n" => 14, "o" => 15,
  "p" => 16, "q" => 17, "r" => 18,
  "s" => 19, "t" => 20, "u" => 21,
  "v" => 22, "w" => 23, "x" => 24,
  "y" => 25, "z" => 26
]

value = word.split("")
puts "Your word, \'#{word}\' has a value of: #{value}"
```

Comment: You can do this in your head, right? Write down on a piece of paper the steps you take to do this yourself. Then figure out how to do each step in Ruby.

Comment: I've been trying, but I'm simply not that good at Ruby yet. After a few hours of tooling around with it, I decided to come here and ask for help.

Comment: Here are some things. First, you can simply define a hash as `{ 'a' => 1, ...}`. Using `[]` to define a hash lets you input an array. You are basically mixing two conventions. Next, given a string, you do not need to use `split` if you want all the characters. Just use `string.chars`, which produces the array you need. Finally, you don't need to escape `'` (single quotes) inside a double-quote string.

Comment: There is no need to construct a hash with 26 elements when you can write a small method to return the value for each letter: `def alphabet(c); c.ord - 96; end; alphabet('z') #=> 26`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) method to add up the values of each char.

```
value = word.split("")
sum = value.reduce(0) {|sum, char| alphabet[char] + sum }
puts "Your word, \'#{word}\' has a value of: #{sum}"
#=> Your word, 'cab' has a value of: 6
```

Here we use `reduce` (which has an alias method `inject`) to reduce the array into a single value.  We start with initial value of `0`, and iterate through each element of the array - in the block, we add the numeric equivalent of given char to the `sum` so far - and eventually end up with sum of all numeric values.

---

Answer to question in comments:

> My only relevant follow-up question to this, is it possible to define
>   the hash using ranges? I know that I can define them with ("a".."z")
>   and (1..26) but I didn't know if there is a way to set those two
>   ranges equal to one another based on their index values or somesuch

You can make use of [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) method that allows to merge two arrays by pairing elements at same index as sub-arrays.  Subsequently, we can take advantage of method [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) which converts any array of 2-element arrays into hash.

```
alphabet = ('a'..'z').zip(1..26).to_h
```

Comment: You can also use `#inject`.

Comment: @HunterStevens  `#reduce` is an alias of `#inject` - both are same

Comment: Appreciate the actual thoughts and suggestions. Not sure why I'm being downvoted...I'm legitimately very new to programming in general and I thought this was the place to go for help.

Comment: @luminaire Upvote and downvotes are not consistent on this forum - sometimes depends on maturity and mood of users I guess

Comment: @WandMaker I know. Was just making a suggestion in case OP sees `inject` suggested elsewhere.

Comment: Truly thanks for the help! This is a good solution and as I was requesting more information about the why, you were posting that very information. Have a great one and thanks again!

Comment: @luminaire if this answer helped you, select it as the accepted answer. You will gain rep from that alone.

Comment: @luminaire Yes.  If you don't pass anything to `inject` the first element of the array will be used as initial value - which in this case would have been character `'c'` - but that would not make sense it in this case as we were meant to add value of `alphabet['c']`.  Hence, we must pass explicit initial value - `0` makes sense as we are summing values.

Comment: My only relevant follow-up question to this, is it possible to define the hash using ranges? 

I know that I can define them with ("a".."z") and (1..26) but I didn't know if there is a way to set those two ranges equal to one another based on their index values or somesuch. Also sorry I'm not sure how to signify code within a comment >< Much noob

Comment: Perhaps `sum = word.each_char.reduce(0)...`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest the following as a good Ruby-way:

```
base = 'a'.ord-1
"catsup".each_char.map { |c| c.ord - base }.reduce(:+)
  #=> 80
```

Breaking it down:

```
d = 'a'.ord
  #=> 97 
base = d-1
  #=> 96 
e = "catsup".each_char.map { |c| c.ord - base }
  #=> [3, 1, 20, 19, 21, 16] 
e.reduce(:+)
  #=> 80
```

Let's look more carefully at the calculation of `e`:

```
enum0 = "catsup".each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "catsup":each_char>
```

Note:

```
enum0.map { |c| c.ord - base }
  #=> [3, 1, 20, 19, 21, 16]
```

To see the elements of the enumerator `enum0`, which will be passed to `map`, convert it to an array:

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> ["c", "a", "t", "s", "u", "p"]
```

Now lets write:

```
enum1 = enum0.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "catsup":each_char>:map>
```

Study the return value. You can think of `enum1` as a "compound" enumerator.

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> ["c", "a", "t", "s", "u", "p"] 
enum1.each { |c| c.ord - base }
  #=> [3, 1, 20, 19, 21, 16]
```

We can now use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to extract each element of `enum`, set the block variable `c` to that value and perform the block calculation:

```
c = enum1.next #=> "c" 
c.ord - base  #=> 99-96 = 3 

c = enum1.next #=> "a" 
c.ord - base  #=> 1

c = enum1.next #=> "t"
c.ord - base  #=> 20 

c = enum1.next #=> "s" 
c.ord - base  #=> 19 

c = enum1.next #=> "u" 
c.ord - base  #=> 21 

c = enum1.next #=> "p" 
c.ord - base  #=> 16 

c = enum1.next #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```